# query for hidden result with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have the following entry in my table:

```
TABLE
profile_id | name | 
s2SN07      Ferry
```

QUERY

```
SELECT profile_id,name,sirname FROM users 
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE 'f%' AND profile_id != "s2SN07" ORDER BY name DESC
```

As a result the query shows me Ferry, but it shouldn't, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You have a quote to much in your `profile_id` search string. Change

```
"'s2SN07"
```

to

```
"s2SN07"
```

Comment: no sorry, my bad, in the query ther isn't "'s2SN07" but is "s2SN07"